# Pass data in URI scheme invocation(Deeplink) Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.forms, deep-linking

As per the geotab uri scheme invocation(deeplink) I can launch geotab drive app from any mobile application. To pass data in the URI structure mentioned in document is of type rison uri. However the same is not recognised in application(Xamarin form). Any help is appreciated. Sample code as below:

`string uri = "geotabdrive://login,(next:dvir/main,credentials:  (database:'mydb',userName:'myUserName',sessionId:'mySessionId'),server:'my.geotab.com')";`

`if (await Launcher.CanOpenAsync(uri)) { var isLaunched = await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(uri); }`

Please help me to pass the credential information to geotab drive app

As of now I figured out an solution: NSUrl is able to parse the same. So using dependency service we can invoke the same.

Comment: in iOS NSUrl is able to parse the uri. So using dependency service we can invoke the required code in iOS project head.

Comment: Seem that you have found one solution now.